# Limit throughput with RxJava

Tags: android, multithreading, functional-programming, rx-java, observable

The case I'm into right now is quite hard to explain so I will write a simpler version just to explain the issue.

I have an `Observable.from()` which emits a sequence of files defined by an `ArrayList` of files. All of these files should be uploaded to a server. For that I have an function that does the job and returns an `Observable`.

```
Observable<Response> uploadFile(File file);
```

When I run this code it gets crazy, the `Observable.from()` emits all of the files and they are uploaded all at ones, or at least for a max of threads it can handle.

I want to have a max of 2 file uploads in parallel. Is there any operator that can handle this for me?

I tried **buffer**, **window** and some others but they seems to only emit two items together instead of having two parallel file uploads constantly. I also tried to set a max threads pool on the uploading part, but this cannot be used in my case.

There should be a simple operator for this right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think all files are uploaded in parallel because you're using `flatMap()`, which executes all transformations simultaneously. Instead you should use `concatMap()`, which runs one transformation after another. And to run two parallel uploads you need to call `window(2)` on you files observable and then invoke `flatMap()` as you did in your code.

```
Observable<Response> responses = 
    files
      .window(2)
      .concatMap(windowFiles ->
        windowFiles.flatMap(file -> uploadFile(file));
      );
```

**UPDATE**:

I found a better solution, which does exactly what you want. There's an overload of `flatMap()` that accepts the max number of concurrent threads.

```
Observable<Response> responses = 
    files
      .onBackpressureBuffer()
      .flatMap(index -> {
        return uploadFile(file).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
      }, 2);
```

Comment: This sounds perfect! I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Nice the window operator works perfect now! How can I make that window moving? Right now if the window emits file 1 and file 2 for upload it waits until both are finished. Can the upload of file 3 already be executed if file 2 is complete and 1 is still in progress?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with default operators so you may have to write your own operator.

Comment: The window(2, 1) operator seems to be doing the job. This defines that a new window will be created after 1 item has skipped. Could you please verify this to confirm?

Comment: No, `window(2, 1)` will not work as you expect. But I found a better solution and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Amazing!