# OOM issue while copying couchbase documents from one bucket to another bucket using reactive programming

Tags: rx-java, couchbase, reactive

We are trying to copy data from one bucket to another using reactive programming(around 1 million documents). We are getting OOM in this piece of code. I am no rxjava expert and need help in order to prevent OOM. I think the read is happening faster than the write and that’s causing the OOM due to buffer getting full. The code is as follows:

```
CountDownLatch countDownLatch5 = new CountDownLatch(1);
Observable
        .from(n1qlKeysForDocsGPC)
        .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<JsonDocument> call(String key) {
                return readPrimaryMainAsyncBucket
                        .get(key, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .onErrorResumeNext(readPrimaryMainAsyncBucket.get(key, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                        .retry(50)
                        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.empty())
                        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<JsonDocument, Observable<JsonDocument>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<JsonDocument> call(JsonDocument jsonDocument) {
                return readPrimaryBackupAsyncBucket.upsert(jsonDocument, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).retry(50);
            }
        })
        .last()
        .doOnTerminate(new Action0() {
            @Override
            public void call() {
                countDownLatch5.countDown();
            }
        })
        .subscribe();
try {
    countDownLatch5.await();
    logger.info("DataRecoverySchedulers | Completed countDownLatch5");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Couchbase Java SDK versions up before 3.x (which is not out yet as of this writing) use RxJava version 1.

The `flatmap` calls, as you have them now, will post operations to an internal buffer to execute asynchronously, returning an `Observable` to track each one. That means the first `flatmap` will consume output of your `from` call in an unbounded way.  In other words, it will read the whole list much faster than the operations happen.  I expect the OOM error you're seeing is from overrunning the Couchbase internal buffer.

To correct this, you can use a variant of `flatmap` that limits the number of outstanding subscriptions.  You just add an second, integer parameter to your `flatmap` call.  So you'd have `.flatmap(new Func1<~>..., 10)` to limit yourself to 10 outstanding ops at a time.

The default buffer in Couchbase is around 16000 outstanding ops, but that's far more than you need to saturate most systems.

For reference, see this related [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383322/limit-throughput-with-rxjava) on limiting throughput for file uploads.